# How to check whether the pattern is present or not in given image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I am currently doing my project in image-processing. In my project, I have to find some patterns.

 For example, This is our test image
[image]

And in this image, I want to find the following pattern.

Pattern:
[image]

I have a report by the ASTM standard that this test image has a 2.5 % given pattern. 
So, Is there any method available that can find the percentage of matching patterns.

I am using OpenCV for image processing in C++.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct method for this purpose.

Comment: Can you define "finding a pattern", "having a pattern" and "having 2.5% given pattern"?

Comment: In the test image, there are many flakes. Some are thin, some are thick from the middle. some flakes are uniformly distributed and some group of flake makes clusters. So, from in test image out of total flakes, how many flakes have formed that cluster like pattern image. So, I want to find that percentage.

Comment: .... its you again. What research did you do?  opencv template matching is for something more exactly looking. You are more like finding similarity in feature and feature characteristic and feature group? thats whole different level of thing